# Incidence Algebra Mobius Function/Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

I'm a little bit confused on how the Mobius Matrix came from, using the Hasse Diagram. [image]

From the article, the Mobius function is defined as follows:

$$\mu(a,b)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } a=b ;\\ 0 & \text{if }  a\neq b \text{ and }\\ -\sum_{c:a \leq c <b} \mu(a,c) & \text{if } a<b \end{cases}$$

My attempt is:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0& 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0& 0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}

but i got it wrong in $\mu(a,d)=-1$, since from the article the Mobius matrix is:
[image]
I don't get to know why i am wrong, since based on the hasse diagram $a \leq d$.

Comment: Can't make out your definition of the function.

Comment: What is the article you are working from? The definition of the möbius function looks incorrect.

Comment: hi it's entitled as the chromatic polynomial, that's why im confused since im not getting the same answer in that article.

Comment: Can you be more specific, e.g. author? Better yet, can you provide a link to the article?

Comment: https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/fouts.pdf this is hte article ive been reading,its page 9-10 on the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for the mobius function you provided is not correct (you have a "$a\neq b$" when it should be "$a\not\leq b$", and the "$a<c$" should be $a\leq c$"); as seen in the source article,

$$\mu(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x=y\\0&\text{if }
x\not\leq y\\
-\displaystyle\sum_{z:x\leq z<y}\mu(x,z)&\text{if }x<y\end{cases}$$

Now, we want to find $\mu(a,d)$. Since $a<d$, we need to find all $z$ such that $a\leq z<d$. Its clear that $z=a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfy that inequality. Therefore,

$$\mu(a,d)=-(\mu(a,a)+\mu(a,b)+\mu(a,c))=-(1+\mu(a,b)+\mu(a,c))$$

To find $\mu(a,b)$ and $\mu(a,c)$, we do the same thing as above. We can find that $$\mu(a,b)=-(\mu(a,a)) = -1\quad\text{ and }\quad\mu(a,c)=-(\mu(a,a)) = -1.$$

Therefore,

$$\mu(a,d)=-(1-1-1)=-(-1)=1.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, maam/sir.

Comment: hi, why does $\mu (a,c)= -(\mu (a,a))$? is it because $a$ is the lower bound of both $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @jennkim Since $a<c$, we have that $\mu(a,c)=-\displaystyle\sum_{z:a\leq z<c}\mu(a,z)$. Since $z=a$ is the only value that satisfies $a\leq z<c$, we have $-\displaystyle\sum_{z:a\leq z<c}\mu(a,z)=-\mu(a,a)$.